# One Django Project, Multiple Settings.py

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

Recently I am to develop a CRM system with an e-commerce module. Since customers only log into the e-commerce website (log in with Email), staff only log into CRM,

I want to separate these two authentication model. Is it a good idea to have two sets of settings.py, one using staff as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, the other one using customer as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? (Maybe separate urls.py as well)

I'm going to run two different settings of app under two sub path or two domain, is this going to cause any issue? (Like concurrency issue ?)

Comment: why do you want to separate them? isnot it easier to separate the logic in model level rather than messing up with settings?

Comment: @doniyor Is it possible to achieve that by having two user model, one for admin site, one for commercial site? If so, how to set up the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? In my situation, the customer and staff can have the same username (or other login token), is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. i will try to explain in an answer in a second

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to set two `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` 's or two settings for this purpose which probabyly would work but this is not the level this logic belongs to. (settings is already in deployment level e.g. running multiple websites on the same codebase and same databse etc etc...)

what I would recommend is something simple:

```
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.CustomUser'

# yourapp's models.lpy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="customuser")
    crm_staff = models.Boolean(default=False)
    # ...
```

and depending on `crm_staff`, the user is either crm-user or just an external user. I set the default value of `crm_staff` to `False`, so that you have to give it explicitly everytime a new user comes in, but only if user is a crm staff, then you need to set the field to `True`

keep it as simple as possible, you say thanks to yourself for this later..